# \makecell - space after word wrap

Tags: makecell, longtblr

I use table "longtblr" and inside I use "\makecell[{{p{5cm}}}]{abcd}".

I want to add shift/space before "defined by default)" , like in "Option 2".

[image: What I have and What I want]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\makecell`, use it directly after `01 -`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
  Option 2:          \\
  00 -- first option \\
  01 -- \makecell[t{{p{4cm}}}]{second option (this option is defined by default)}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: code with makecell]

But maybe il would be preferable to use two columns and set `--` as column separator with `@{...}`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l @{~--~} p{4cm}}
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Option 2:}          \\
  00 & first option \\
  01 & second option (this option is defined by default)
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also makecell inside makecell worked for me.

Comment: @ikif Of course, `\makecell` creates a one-column tabular. You can nest as many as you want.